# python prime numbers in one liner

Tags: python

Do you think this is the kind of fastest way to get the prime numbers below the specified number in one liner:

```
[p for p in xrange(3,1000000) if p%2 != 0 and 0 not in (p%d for d in xrange(3,int(p**0.5)+1))]
```

Comment: This is just trial division, and a very inefficient implementation at that. The [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) is much faster, but also harder to implement (especially in a single line).

Comment: It's also worth noting that questions prefixed with "Do you think" are generally not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Writing things in list comprehension doesn't make algorithm efficient.

Comment: You're asking a silly question that has a one word answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think that lines are cheap, and that you should write readable code, on multiple lines where necessary.

In this case, it's necessary. Also, if you need to use this for anything other than a Project Euler problem, you should use a Prime sieve found in a library.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing compact code with efficient code. There *are* ways to increase the efficiency of the above code, but it won't matter if you do it in one line or in 10 lines. Python compiles the human readable code to bytecode *before* execution. You have no control over how many bytecode instructions your code is converted to.

It's true that list comprehensions are generally faster than `for` loops but not universally true. It's also generally true that using implied loops such as `map()` are usually faster.  The `timeit` and `dis` modules are your friends. That way, you can find out for yourself whether a certain piece of code is faster than another.

Premature optimization is foolishness. Identify the bottlenecks in your code *before* you start tinkering. Can  you identify which part of the above code is likely to be slowing it down the most?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah yeah yeah, you shouldn't do this in one line. For reasons. But I like a good challenge.

Here's what I came up with as a one liner, that is 'reasonably' fast. Its a wonderfully convoluted mess, but it works. It can be 'shorter', but I found that the 'if step%3 or step==3' actually sped things up by eliminating a third of the work.. And using set comprehensions.. If you don't care if the list is sorted, you can shave some by removing the sorted() call.

```
[2] + sorted(set(xrange(3,max,2)) - { x for step in xrange(3, int(max**0.5) + 1, 2) if step %3 or step==3 for x in xrange(step * 3, max, step * 2)} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Was wondering the same... Why not just:

```
[2] + [x for x in xrange(3,max,2) if not [y for y in xrange(3,int(x**0.5)+1,2) if x%y==0]]
```

Comment: Surprisingly, 10x faster on pypy:

Comment: >>>> timeit('[2] + [x for x in xrange(3,max,2) if not [y for y in xrange(3,int(x**0.5)+1,2) if x%y==0]]', 'max=1000000', number=1)

1.110201120376587